# Python Selenium: How to wait until href attribute contains a specific string?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

For example, I'm opening page `https://example.com/page-1/` in Selenium, looking for a specific link that contains `domain.com`. Right now I'm using `sleep(20)` to ensure the page has fully loaded. But I wonder if I can use `WebDriverWait` not only for tag presence but also for its contains presence as well. Could not find any solution yet...

Comment: yes you can do it in a lambda expression

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I'm not yet familiar with lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, I'm assuming that you are using Firefox but the logic is the same:

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get('https://example.com/page-1/')
#wait for a maximum of 60 seconds in this example
wait = WebDriverWait(firefox, 60)
domain = "domain.com"
wait.until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_css_selector(f"a[href*='{domain}']"))
```

Answer (score 2):

To wait for the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) for the href attribute to contain a specific string, you can induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Full match of `domain.com`:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='domain.com']")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='domain.com']")))
    ```
- Partial match of `domain.com`:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='domain.com']")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'domain.com')]")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```